# Mongo shell stops responding to commands

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell

I am playing around a little with the mongo shell, but I have quite a tedious problem.

After I've switched to the database I'm working with using "use nameOfDatabase", and I issue my first command, the shell won't respond to any further commands after giving me the first response. I have to CTRL + C or CTRL + Z out of it, reconnect, switch to the db again and then issue another command to keep working.

Also, accessing commands from the history does not work since this just moves the cursor around the shell window (this also makes the shell stop responding).

Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Z` is for 'suspend'. Try `Ctrl+D` to exit the mongo prompt.